# What is the correct solution to 16/4(4)?

Tags: mathematics, explanation

This has been circulated recently. We all know the order of the calculation: [BEDMAS](http://mathsfirst.massey.ac.nz/Algebra/OrderOfOp/orderAlg.htm).

- B rackets and Parentheses: First Priority
- E xponents: Second Priority
- D ivision: Third Priority
- M ultiplication: Third Priority
- A ddition: Fourth Priority
- S ubtraction: Fourth Priority

The problem is how if it's `4(4)`? Is it using multiplication priority? Or is it using brackets and parentheses priority? My guess is using multiplication priority, but I rarely see any website talking about this priority for "multiplying to bracket" thing. Reading the comments section in the social media post where this is shared makes me even more confused because people are fighting each other over which one is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a puzzle and will no doubt be closed soon, but if you use priority as stated, you are asking whether multiplication has precedence over division, and since they are at the same level, you do them in order so (16/4)*4
The (4) is just 4, don't be confused by the redundant parentheses

Comment: I realize that, given this is a Q&A platform, it's easy to think the point here is to answer people's questions.  It isn't.  The point is to create a repository of questions and their answers, about Puzzles and their creation and solving, that will be of use to current and future visitors.  We do that by keeping off-topic questions and irrelevant or redundant answers out, and that's something *everyone in the community* ideally is helping to do. If you know it's off topic and should be closed, maybe help the asker understand why in a comment, but then please **vote to close**, don't answer it.